# Which -x to use for preprocessing through GCC?

Tags: gcc, c-preprocessor

I need to use GCC (4.8.1 in my case) to run the preprocessor on a file which contains preprocessor directives, but not (necessarily) C/C++ code. These directives can depend on GCC's pre-defined macros, so I have to invoke the preprocessor through GCC instead of directly. I know that I can do that by using GCC's option `-E`.

The file can have an arbitrary extension, so I need to specify its type by the `-x` command-line option. I've looked into GCC docs and found four values for this option which could make sense in my situation:

```
c
c-header
c++
c++-header
```

The docs provide little info about them except for their names. So my question is: what is the difference between them? Are they equivalent for my purpose of running the preprocessor only, or is there something I should we wary about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-header` variants are for the precompiled header ("PCH") feature.  PCH doesn't really make sense in conjunction with `-E`, so you should just ignore those.

The choice of `-x c` versus `-x c++` decides some features of the preprocessor -- C and C++ are not identical here.  You can also affect preprocessor features using `-std=...`.

You can also put the preprocessor into an old K&R compatibility mode with `-traditional` (you may need `-Wp,-traditional`, I forget).  This is sometimes used when preprocessing non-source files, though not always.  This mode affects many things, see the manual for details.